Unable to load Webview in MAUI Android
I have a Webview that  I want to display inside a StackLayout. This works fine on MAUI iOS, but does not appear on MAUI Android. Am I missing something in MAUI Android?
Update: I tried to display a text only in the Webview source and it is displaying fine in iOS Maui, but not in Android Maui.
    <StackLayout
            Margin="20"
            Spacing="0">
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Spacing="0">
                <Label
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                    FontSize="{x:Static portable:FontHelper.TitleText}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold" />

                <buttons:ButtonPrimary
                    Text="{x:Static portable:StringResources.Activate}"
                    Command="{Binding ActivateCommand}"
                    Margin="0, 30, 0, 0"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <portable:BorderLine 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0, 30"/>

            <WebView
                HeightRequest="{OnPlatform Default='-1', Android='600', iOS='566'}"
                IsVisible="{Binding HtmlContent, Converter={StaticResource notNullToBoolConverter}}">
                <WebView.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:WebViewAutoHeightEffectBehavior />
                </WebView.Behaviors>
                <WebView.Source>
                    <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding HtmlContent.Value}" />
                </WebView.Source>
            </WebView>
         
        </StackLayout>  


What is the type of HtmlContent.Value here?

Please provide more context. What are you trying to display in the WebView? A local file? Content from a URL? Is the WebView inside a StackLayout?

@Julian I am trying to display a webview inside a stacklayout

I updated the code above

@error404 Try setting a WidthRequest as well and remove the Default='-1'' from the HeightRequest`. What are you trying to display?

A WebView must specify its HeightRequest and WidthRequest properties when contained in a HorizontalStackLayout, StackLayout, or VerticalStackLayout. If you fail to specify these properties, the WebView will not render.

@liyu the xamarin version of this code works perfectly fine in both iOS and Android. And now using Maui, it now only works in iOS but not in Android.

@Julian I’m trying to display a bunch of texts and images in Webview. My implementation works when I run it in iOS, but when I run it in android, it displays nothing.

Yes, I understood that already, but what is behind HtmlContent.Value that you're binding to? And have you tried with a WidthRequest?

@Julian It is a contenftul that I'm trying to display in the page. I tried the WidthRequest and sometimes the content is being displayed and sometimes it is not in Android. I wonder if this is some sort of issue in Android Maui. I'm noticing that Android is very slow when running the MAUI app.

@Julian I tried to display a text only inside the webview source, and it is not displaying as well. Could be the implementation of the webview in iOS Maui is different in Android Maui? The text is displaying fine in iOS Maui.

Without more information about what you're trying to display, it will be difficult to tell what could be wrong. Anyway, yes, the implementations of WebView are different between iOS and Android, they use native views under the hood (like many other UI elements).

@Julian I did a trial and error to test if Webview is working or my actual content is the one that is not working. So I removed the Binding HtmlContent.Value in the source and replaced it with a string "TEST", I also removed the IsVisible. I also added a background color of the Webview, this changes are use to validate if the WebView is working or not. After these changes, the TEST string with the background color is not showing in Android but it is showing in iOS. So meaning, the WebView itself is not working in Android MAUI.

@error404 Well, if you suspect a bug in MAUI, you should search and possibly file a new issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues
